# Each row (object) with own binding source in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I'm writing a small application in C# (.NET 4.0). I have a datagridview, each row represents one object. I want a combobox column that allows to choose a specific property of that object.

**Example:**

```
public class Car
{
   public String Make {get; set;}
   public BindingList<String> AllColors {get; set;}
   public int SelectedColorIndex {get; set;}
}
```

Each row represents one Car object. Each (different) car object has it's own selection of possible colors (AllColors). I want to have a column where you can set SelectedColorIndex by choosing one of the colors from AllColors (AllColors is specific to each Car object).

Note: I made up this example but it describes what I want to accomplish.

How can I accomplish this?  The only solution that I found was to have a specific combobox outside of the datagridview using which you can change the selected row. And in row enter event I changed the datasource of the bindingsource to the current "AllColors".

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: So you want the combobox for each car to offer a different set of colours? Are the colours for each car a subset of all the available colours?

Comment: Yes. Each car has its own available colors and they are not a subset of any "larger available colors" set. (this is just an example in my case each object has it's own set of available properties, which again are objects. I made this example up to make things more simple).

Comment: I'll have an example that hopefully answers the question shortly. About halfway through prototyping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code behind of a working example where the colors available are filtered down to the colors provided in the bound object's AllColors list.

The magic happens in the `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` event handlers - there we provide each combo box cell with the list from the bound row and then reset it on exit.

One thing this relies upon is having a master list which contains all colours - there is no way around this.

Also I've added handling for the case where a new row needs default values. All I do is set the selected index by default to one. Of course this wouldn't work in the real world, you would need something a bit smarter! The `DefaultValuedNeeded` event is describe [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b22t666e.aspx).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private BindingSource cars;
    private BindingSource masterColors;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        masterColors = new BindingSource();
        masterColors.Add(new CarColor{Name = "Blue", Index = 1});
        masterColors.Add(new CarColor{Name = "Red", Index = 2});
        masterColors.Add(new CarColor { Name = "Green", Index = 3 });
        masterColors.Add(new CarColor { Name = "White", Index = 4 });

        BindingList<CarColor> fordColors = new BindingList<CarColor>();
        fordColors.Add(new CarColor{Name = "Blue", Index = 1});
        fordColors.Add(new CarColor{Name = "Red", Index = 2});

        BindingList<CarColor> toyotaColors = new BindingList<CarColor>();
        toyotaColors.Add(new CarColor { Name = "Green", Index = 3 });
        toyotaColors.Add(new CarColor { Name = "White", Index = 4 });

        cars = new BindingSource();
        cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Ford", SelectedColorIndex = 1, AllColors = fordColors });
        cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Toyota", SelectedColorIndex = 3, AllColors = toyotaColors });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = cars;
        dataGridView1.Columns["SelectedColorIndex"].Visible = false;
        //dataGridView1.Columns["AllColors"].Visible = false;

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        col.Name = "AvailableColors";
        col.DataSource = masterColors;
        col.DisplayMember = "Name";
        col.DataPropertyName = "SelectedColorIndex";
        col.ValueMember = "Index";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);

        dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += new DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit);
        dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
        dataGridView1.DefaultValuesNeeded += new DataGridViewRowEventHandler(dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded);
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["AvailableColors"].Index)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
            {
                // Set the combobox cell datasource to the filtered BindingSource
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1
                                [e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                Car rowCar = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Car;
                dgcb.DataSource = rowCar.AllColors;
            }

        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["AvailableColors"].Index)
        {
            // Reset combobox cell to the unfiltered BindingSource
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1
                            [e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            dgcb.DataSource = masterColors; //unfiltered
        }
    }

    void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells["SelectedColorIndex"].Value = 1;
    }

}

public class Car
{
    public String Make { get; set; }
    public BindingList<CarColor> AllColors { get; set; }
    public int SelectedColorIndex { get; set; }
}

public class CarColor
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I first learned how to do this from the [DataGridView FAQ](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF4QFjAA&url=http://windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%2520To%2520Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%2520FAQ.doc&ei=dNPlT8XEEIrtsgbjq8WjAQ&usg=AFQjCNFxVe3EWtsJNP7xXxENGfV6dxU0EQ), a great resource written by Mark Rideout, the program manager at the time for the `DataGridView` at Microsoft. The example in the FAQ filters based upon another combobox, and uses DataTables but the principle is the same.